# How to pass configuration via argocd and crossplane

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd, crossplane

We are trying to create an environment using crossplane and argocd. Once Crossplane generates the database and saves the credentials to a secret on the management cluster. After we are deploying the credentials from management cluster to our destination cluster to a secret.

Now we need to pass the credentials from secret a to secret B which the application knows about. The issue starts when argo do not use helm install but template thus `lookup` function don't work. We thought about using vault as a middle man but we are not sure how to load values from secret to vault.

Anyway if you encounter such an issue or have some sort of a solution we'll be very happy to hear.
Thank you

Comment: Argo is really meant for GitOps, meaning your secret should be declarative. If your secret is generated by an application (dynamically), its not a great fit for replication via Argo bc you would need to commit it to git after its initialized. you should look towards `kubed` for secret replication!

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit the (encrypted) secrets somewhere for ArgoCD to pick them up. That is the whole point of GitOps.

Alternatively you can try using https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/parameters/ but this is considered a temporary workaround